# Load UICollectionView Cells Early

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm writing a custom view controller transition that animates views from one view controller to another. Part of this requires me to have loaded the collection view by the time `animateTransition` is called (from `<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>` protocol). I've found that the collection view cells aren't loaded by this time.

1) When do the collection view cells get loaded?

2) Is there a way to load them in early?

Comment: They should be fairly instant. Are you doing any heavy calculations during the creation of each cell?

Comment: It's not that it is taking long to do. This collection view operation is just happening later in the draw cycle. I called `layoutIfNeeded` and that worked, but then it had the frame size initially set to 600x600 which is a problem.